# Fragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity in rss reader

Tags: android, fragment, android-adapter, rss-reader

I followed [this](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/tutorial-para-crear-un-lector-rss-en-android/) tutorial in order to create an rss reader (Unfortunately, it is in Spanish). However, as my rss must be inside a Fragment I converted the MainActivity into a fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.my.app.MainActivity_tabs;
import com.my.app.Modelo.FeedDatabase;
import com.my.app.Modelo.ScriptDatabase;
import com.my.app.R;
import com.my.app.RssParse.Rss;
import com.my.app.Web.VolleySingleton;
import com.my.app.Web.XmlRequest;

/**
 * Creado por Hermosa Programación
 *
 * Actividad principal que representa el Home de la aplicación
 */

public class News extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = MainActivity_tabs.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String URL_FEED = "www.forbes.com/fdc/rss.html";

private ListView listView;

private FeedAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab2, container, false);


    // Obtener la lista
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lista);

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
                new XmlRequest<>(
                        URL_FEED,
                        Rss.class,
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<Rss>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Rss response) {
                                // Caching
                                FeedDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).
                                        sincronizarEntradas(response.getChannel().getItems());
                                // Carga inicial de datos...
                                new LoadData().execute();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                )
        );
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "La conexión a internet no está disponible");
        adapter = new FeedAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                FeedDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).obtenerEntradas(),
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    // Regisgrar escucha de la lista
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);

            // Obtene url de la entrada seleccionada
            String url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ScriptDatabase.ColumnEntradas.URL));

            // Nuevo intent explícito
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);

            // Setear url
            i.putExtra("url-extra", url);

            // Iniciar actividad
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Carga inicial de registros
        return FeedDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).obtenerEntradas();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);

        // Crear el adaptador
        adapter = new FeedAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                cursor,
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        // Relacionar la lista con el adaptador
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

}
```

But when I run the app, I get the following error and I cannot figure it out why this happens, any ideas?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.UI.News}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.app.UI.News cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1232)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.app.UI.News cannot be  cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1232)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent that previously was starting `News` which was an activity is trying to start `News` now which is a fragment (probably because the manifest has `News` as your default launcher Activity). Your fragment needs to be held inside an activity instead.

See the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) on how to add a fragment to an activity.

Comment: I don't know how I could be so stupid! Thank you very much!